# Apache Ignite javax.cache.CacheException: Indexing is disabled for cache

Tags: ignite

When I run the following code, an exception that Apache Ignite javax.cache.CacheException: Indexing is disabled for cache is thrown.
Not sure where the problem lies. Could someone help? Thanks!

```
package com.xyz.ignite.sqlgrid;

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder;

import javax.cache.Cache;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Arrays;


import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.annotations.QuerySqlField;

class Person {
    @QuerySqlField
    private String name;

    @QuerySqlField
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}

public class IgniteSQLQueryTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String configPath = "D:/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/config/default-config.xml";
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(configPath);
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, Person> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<Integer, Person>();
        cfg.setName("person_cache");
        cfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, Person.class);
        Cache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);
        String cacheName = cache.getName();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.setAge(i);
            p.setName("name-" + i);
            cache.put(i, p);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("Cache get:" + cache.get(i));
        }

        Class.forName("org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcDriver");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:ignite:cfg://cache=%s@file:///%s", cacheName, configPath));
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select name from Person");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String name1 = rs.getString(1);
            System.out.println(name1);
        }

        ignite.close();
    }
}
```

an exception occurred,the exception message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Failed to query Ignite.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc2.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:115)
    at com.xyz.ignite.sqlgrid.IgniteSQLQueryTest.main(IgniteSQLQueryTest.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: javax.cache.CacheException: Indexing is disabled for cache: person_cache. Use setIndexedTypes or setTypeMetadata methods on CacheConfiguration to enable.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.validate(IgniteCacheProxy.java:732)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:664)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc2.JdbcQueryTask.call(JdbcQueryTask.java:158)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc2.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:102)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks that I find where the problem lies.The Person Pojo should be

```
class Person implements Serializable {
    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private String name;

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private int age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

The QuerySqlField annotation should add an `index = true` parameter

Comment: This parameter only controls whether an index is created for a particular field. If it's `false` or not set, the field will not be indexed, but it will be queryable. Having said that, I doubt that this was the reason of the exception. Can you provide your test (ideally as a small GitHub project) so that I can reproduce and investigate?